# What is the difference between congruence class, residue class and equivalent class?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, definition

They all seems same to me. Is there any difference?

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: Congruence class and residue class are one and the same: the class of a  number $a$  is all those integers giving the same remainder as $a$ (we assume we are working with division by a pre-determined number $m$, called the modulus). Equivalence class is a more general terminology.  Being congruent modulo a given $m$ is an example of an equivalence relation.